# read key-value from file using shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I have one of configuration file e.g. called (abc.conf)

```
abc.conf
------- 
location1=/opt/test1/locationx
location2=/opt/test1/locationy
location3=/opt/test1/locationz
```

I have sample code which works fine if I am not using such path and slashes

```
getProperty()
{
PROPERTY_FILE=$1
PROP_KEY=$2
PROP_VALUE=`cat $PROPERTY_FILE | grep -w "$PROP_KEY" | cut -d'=' -f2`
echo $PROP_VALUE
}
```

Using like

```
VALUE=$(getProperty $CONF_FILE $LOCATION1)
```

But this function have limitation using it, when I use it like to fetch location1 it also fetches location2/location3  like similar location together instead specific key value only. it should work with unique value only.

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to achieve. Can you add the values of $PROPERTY_FILE and $PROP_KEY

Answer (score 0):

This code is working.

Calling function,

```sh
$ getProperty abc.conf location1(2 or 3)
/opt/test1/locationx
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `awk` to properly restrict the key match to the first field.

```
getProperty()
{
    awk -F= -v key=$2 '$1 == key {print $2} "$1"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In Bash 4.3. and newer, you can do this without any external tools or subshells:

```
declare -A locations
while IFS='=' read -d $'\n' -r key value; do
    locations[$key]="$value"
done < abc.conf
```

Access individual locations via their corresponding key, e.g. `locations["location1"]`